# How to Align Center Product Categories from WooCommerce in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm actually very new with Wordpress. I'm using a Woocommerce plugin for the product categories. Does anyone know how to align the products for it to be on the center and position the texts in a landscape orientation? Also for our theme in our homepage, it tends to be positioned on the left rather than on the center if we're using mobile. I have very little to no coding background. Is there any css or any code that I could use? Will really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Here's the website url: http://aom.sg/product-category/air/air-purifiers/ (for products)

http://aom.sg for the homepage

Comment: remove the `width: 22.05%;` from this elements: `.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For homepage services list is left aligned.

```
.service_list ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 300px;
```

If you change margin: 0 to margin: auto, it will help list adjust to center.

i.e.

```
.service_list ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 300px;
```

Comment: Thanks Mohsin! It worked! Can I use the same thing for the client's logos underneath the services? It still seems to be positioned on the left for mobile view. TT

Answer (score 0):

Try to target the .woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product selector and set the width to 100%.

Open your the WordPress customizer in the dashboard, and go to custom CSS. Then  copy paste the snippet below and publish the changes:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this code, it doesn't seem to work on my website. TT